# Setup a grid with Kendo UI using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, grid, kendo-ui

I'm starting developing in HTML and I'm trying to use the Kendo UI framework in ASP.NET MVC.

I started with this tutorial: [Entity Framework 5.x – Database First Workflow](http://hectorea.com/blog/database-first-workflow/#)
With this I was able to create a Web Page that show me a table with data from a database.

But now I want to style de table with Kendo UI widgets (Grid). To do that I followed this video: [Using KendoUI Grids on ASP.Net MVC - Tutorial 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZvj00n26wE&list=PLA3F860848D268A5C&index=3) (until 4:37min)

The steps that I made so far:

- Download trial version of Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC
- Copy `kendo.default.min.css` and `kendo.common.min.css` files from the downloaded folder to the `Content` folder in my Visual Studio project
- Copy `kendo.all.min.js` file from the downloaded folder to the `Scripts` folder
- Changed the `View` with the following code:

> ```
> @model IEnumerable<DatabaseFirst.Models.Artesano>
>
> @{
>     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
> }
>
> <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
> <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
> <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     $(function () {
>         $("#artesanos-grid").kendoGrid();
>
>     });
>
>
> </script>
>
> <h2>Index</h2>
>
> <p>
>     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
> </p>
> <table id="artesanos-grid">
>     <thead>
>     <tr>
>         <th>
>             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RFC)
>         </th>
>         <th>
>             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RazonSocial)
>         </th>
>         <th>
>             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telefonos)
>         </th>
>         <th>
>             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fax)
>         </th>
>         <th>Actions</th>
>     </tr>
>     </thead>
>     <tbody>
> @foreach (var item in Model) {
>     <tr>
>         <td>
>             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RFC)
>         </td>
>         <td>
>             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RazonSocial)
>         </td>
>         <td>
>             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefonos)
>         </td>
>         <td>
>             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fax)
>         </td>
>         <td>
>             @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.RFC }) |
>             @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.RFC }) |
>             @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.RFC })
>         </td>
>     </tr>
> }
>     </tbody>
>
> </table>
> ```

But when I run the page, no changes are made to the grid...
What am I missing?

PS:
The source code of the loaded page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<link href="/Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#artesanos-grid").kendoGrid();

    });


</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a href="/Artesano/Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table id="artesanos-grid">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            RFC
        </th>
        <th>
            RazonSocial
        </th>
        <th>
            Telefonos
        </th>
        <th>
            Fax
        </th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            325
        </td>
        <td>
            sdfwef
        </td>
        <td>
            wetfgvs
        </td>
        <td>
            sdfsdgs
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Artesano/Edit/325">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Artesano/Details/325">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Artesano/Delete/325">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td>
            weg
        </td>
        <td>
            asdgweg
        </td>
        <td>
            dsg
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Artesano/Edit/2">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Artesano/Details/2">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Artesano/Delete/2">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            235423
        </td>
        <td>
            sdga
        </td>
        <td>
            et
        </td>
        <td>
            wefwf
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Artesano/Edit/235423">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Artesano/Details/235423">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Artesano/Delete/235423">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            23
        </td>
        <td>
            wq
        </td>
        <td>
            sasdga
        </td>
        <td>
            aegweg
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Artesano/Edit/23">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Artesano/Details/23">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Artesano/Delete/23">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: DId you check for JS errors the console?

Comment: @PeturSubev As you can see I already solved the problem. But as I am a beginner, can you tell me where I can see JS errors? Is it in Visual Studio or in the browser (Chrome)? It will be useful in the future.

Comment: At your browser's console. I suggest you to check this video , i think you will find it useful.
http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-01-02/screencast_debugging_kendo_ui_applications.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was in the `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`:

The file was generated like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

So I changed to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

(I put the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` at the header)

The problem is now solved.